# keep all lines with >2 duplicates, based on one column

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

I have a file that has millions of lines with the following format:

```
SN608   VB050   1       1113    1699.50 2339.90 0       1       AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCGTCAATTTTTTAAAAAAAACCCCCGGGGGGTAGTTTGTTAAAA   a[_ceeeegggfgiiigecccccccccccccccccccccbcccccccccccTTEHGGHHGJHGJSRGEGGJY]]]TX[[[XEEOX[EEEGGJGGGGJS]  1
```

I have sorted it by column 9 using `sort -k9`.  Column 9 is a 100-letter string, though some entries may have periods.  Now I want to remove lines where the 100-letter string in column 9 only occurs 1 or 2 times (<3 times), and save all other lines to a file.

I played around with `uniq` (`-d -f9 -w100`) and `sort` and suspect `awk` would be helpful, but I am too much of a novice to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store the first and second matches in `outfile` and all other matches in `dups`:

```
awk '++a[$9]>2{print $0>"dups";next}1' file > outfile
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works well for my purposes now, but what if instead I didn't want to discard the first and second matches when there are three or more matches?

Comment: @user2250055 that was my original answer. See now, if this solves your problem please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: I think this was closer: `awk '++a[$9]>2' infile > outfile`.  It successfully saves the strings repeated more than two times, but what I meant was to keep the first and second match of those repeated greater than two time in the output too (not just the 3rd to nth matches).  The other answer (`awk '++a[$9]>2{print $0>"dups";next}1' file > outfile`) seems to just remove duplicates greater than 2.